# How do I ensure a Lambda function waits for call to an async function with await?

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, es6-promise, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to write a lambda function which accepts an image file via web form, and writes it as a new commit to a repository using code commit. For some reason, my lambda function seems to be exiting before the call to createCommit, even though I'm using await in a similar way to my previous calls in the function.

I've tried rewriting the function that wraps createCommit to just use promises, but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm wondering if there is some quirk of lambda that I don't know about or if I'm using async/await incorrectly (I just recently learned how to use them)

this is my main lambda event handler:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   const [file, lastCommitId] = await Promise.all([getFile(event), getLastCommitId()]);

   return await createCommit(file, lastCommitId)
      .then(result => returnResponse(result, 200))
      .catch(err => returnResponse(err, 500));
};
```

this is my wrapper function for createCommit

```
async function createCommit(file, parentCommitId) {
   const fileContent = await file.content.toString('base64');

   const params = {
      "authorName": "admin",
      branchName,
      "commitMessage": "add image",
      "email": "n/a",
      "parentCommitId": parentCommitId,
      "putFiles": [
         {
            fileContent,
            "fileMode": "NORMAL",
            "filePath": `src/images/${file.filename}`
         }
      ],
      repositoryName
   };

   console.log("creating commit against last commit id " + parentCommitId);

   const result = await codecommit.createCommit(params).promise();

   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
   return result;
}
```

I expect the lambda function to wait until the call to createCommit finished, but it simply prints out the console.log starting with "creating commit against last commit..." and exits.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So it turns out I was using async/await correctly, I just had a 3 second timeout on the lambda function, so it was exiting before it was able to get a response from the createCommit call.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `await` and `.then` together.
change your code to and `trycatch` if you want to catch the exception or failed case.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   const [file, lastCommitId] = await Promise.all([getFile(event), getLastCommitId()]);

   return await createCommit(file, lastCommitId);
};
```

See below example to understand the result in a better way.

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds().then(x=>console.log('inside then ', x));
  console.log('after await ',result);
}

asyncCall();
```

and with out then

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log('after await ',result);
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: Please accept this as answer if it resolves your issue

Comment: I removed the .then as you said, but the function still exits before waiting for the call to complete
```javascript
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   const [file, lastCommitId] = await Promise.all([getFile(event), getLastCommitId()]);
   return await createCommit(file, lastCommitId);
};
```

Comment: see `const result = await codecommit.createCommit(params).promise();` this piece of code. this hope's correct. I don't know what `createCommit` is returning. Just make sure you are not adding anything extra similar to `.then`. Make sure your `createCommit ` function is working.

Comment: I think it's a pretty standard part of the AWS SDK, for example this is the getLastCommitId function I wrote, which works and waits for my function to return:

`
async function getLastCommitId() {
   const params = {branchName, repositoryName};
   const result = await codecommit.getBranch(params).promise();
   return result.branch.commitId;
}
`

Comment: Can you please share supporting link if you have any. Also, did you tried removing `.promis()` and tested? sometimes document might have some mistakes.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property

Comment: add try catch to `createCommit` definitely there might be some exception since you are not handling the exception program might be crashing after the call to `const result = await codecommit.createCommit(params).promise();`